# EXT4 partition not recognized by system

Tags: cyanogenmod, partitions, ext4

I partitioned the sdcard with my linux box but it is not mounted by the system. I did fdisk in the phone's terminal and:

```
Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/block/mmcblk0: 7948 MB, 7948206080 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 242560 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 64 * 512 = 32768 bytes

             Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks  Id System
/dev/block/mmcblk0p1   *          33      226176     7236608   c Win95 FAT32 (LBA)
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary
/dev/block/mmcblk0p2          226177      242560      524288  83 Linux
```

I have CM7 for Milestone, it should be supported. Tried with mount -a but there is not even a /etc/fstab. Any ideas? Thanks!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**0.08-11.04.05 RC4:** - 07app2ext script included in /system/etc/init.d - works via bind mount but is compatible with symlink versions. (warning - do not put more than one app2ext script in init.d as it could result in loss of apps)

Checked source from /update-cm-7.0.0-0.08-11.04.18b-Milestone-signed/

system/etc/init.d/05mountsd mounts /dev/block/mmcblk0p2 in boot: `$BB mount -o noatime,nodiratime,barrier=1 -t auto $SD_EXT_PART $SD_EXT_DIRECTORY;` That's reason for empty fstab. Next system/etc/init.d/07app2ext will create directories if needed, move some files if needed and finally bind mount directories from /sd-ext into /data/

Solution: Are you sure you created filesystem instead of only partitioning? 
Check logcat for errors. 
Try to mount with `mount -o noatime,nodiratime,barrier=1 -t auto  /dev/block/mmcblk0p2 /sd-ext`.

Answer (score 0):

[CM does not support apps2ext since version 6](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Apps2SD).

I've heard some users say that you can use [the simple2ext app](https://market.android.com/details?id=ru.krikun.s2e) to do this, though. Should be straightforward.